# How to access user instance in custom login system?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-settings

I want to make a very custom login system and I'm failing to receive the user instance when the token is sent within the `headers`. I have number of APIs which need to work with and without users logged in and need to access the `user.id` (primary key). In my custom `Login`, I want to get the user instance and do a custom check. But I can never access the user even though the token is created and is being sent within the header.

I'm sending the token in header within Postman:

```
"Authorization": "Token {{token}}"
```

`settings.py:`

```
.....

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'channels',
    'corsheaders',
    'pgtrigger',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'myapp'
]

.....

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.User"

.....
```

`login.py:`

```
from typing import Any

from django.db.models import Q

from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from rest_framework.request import Request, QueryDict
from rest_framework.views import APIView

import bcrypt

from myapp.util.functions import contains, API_CallBack
from myapp.util.classes import Error

from myapp.models.user.user import User

class Endpoint(APIView):

    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request: Request):

        # --------------------
        # Get and Check Data
        # --------------------

        print()
        print(request.user)       // NOT GETTING THE USER HERE
        print()

        par: QueryDict = request.data
        if (
            not contains(par) or
            not (par.keys() >= { "id", "password" })
        ): return API_CallBack(Error("gRXIQWhkb6"))

        _return = Error("eKKld8iqrz")
        try:
            _return = Login(request, par["id"], par["password"])
        except Error as e: _return = e
        return API_CallBack(_return)

def Login(request: Request, id: str, password: str) -> dict[str, str]:

    # -------------------------------
    # Check and Format Data
    # -------------------------------

    # req.session.modified = True
    if (
        not contains(request, id, password) or
        Token.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists()
    ): raise Error("ulxdQrfrP2")

    # -------------------------------------
    # Execute Queries and Perform
    # -------------------------------------

    try:
        user: User = User.objects.filter(
            Q(account_name__exact = id) | Q(email__exact = id)
        ).get()

        # Start Session
        if bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode("UTF8"), user.password.encode("UTF8")):
            token: Token = Token.objects.create(user = user)
            return { "token": token.key }

        else:
            raise Error("tSqmORm1y5", 404, "empty", "No record found with inserted inputs")

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Error("h0lddS4Jtn", 404, "empty", "No record found with inserted inputs")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\n{str(e)}\n")

    raise Error("SwZu4K4N1p", message="Token already exists")
```

Comment: You are sending the token, which is [`TokenAuthentication`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) and thus you need to add `TokenAuthentication` to your `authentication_classes`

Comment: Hi @JPG, firstly thanks for commenting. So, I have added `TokenAuthentication` in the list after `SessionAuthentication` but I receive the response of `{ "detail": "User inactive or deleted." }`. I do not want an auto reject response as I want to achieve a custom check. Thanks. This is important as some of my custom APIs need to work with and without login and need to access the `user.id`.

Comment: Your user is not marked as active, so their token is not valid, therefor they are not logged in.  Why is your user inactive?   If you really want different behavior, you will need either/both: custom permissions class / authentication backend.  You can derive from the base class in the token package if that is the case.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, the `user` is marked as active. The `is_active` value is `True` since its creation.

Comment: Then where does this error come from, which you say you get: `{ "detail": "User inactive or deleted." }`?  That is raised _directly_ by the TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication if `is_active=False`.  Session auth, oddly, just returns None so you should get the default error.

Comment: @Andrew Can you submit an answer of the above comment in my question so I can accept it? `is_active = False` was the issue. Thanks

Comment: I have added the answer.  Thank you for following up and for asking for a proper answer to be posted, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `user.is_active` may be `False`.

It appears that the specific error message you are seeing is raised directly from the [`TokenAuthentiation`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L205) or [`BasicAuthentication`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L103) class.

```
if not token.user.is_active:
    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('User inactive or deleted.'))
```

Session auth, to my surprise, doesn't raise this.